# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos x}{y-1}$ by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My first step was to multiply both sides by $dx$ and by $y-1$ to get $(y-1)dy=\cos x dx$. Now I integrate both sides to get $\frac{y^2}{2}-y=\sin x+c$. Now I multiplied both sides of the equation by 2 and get $y^2-2y=2\sin x+c$. Which is $y(y-2)=2\sin x+c$. And it’s at this point that I’m stuck. I’m having trouble with the LHS. If I rewrite the original equation as $y’-\frac{\cos x}{y-1}=0$. I’m not sure that clears the way for me to proceed with separation of variables.

Comment: You did the hardest part. Look at $y^2-2y-2\sin x$ as a polynomial of degree 2 in $x$.  You can find its roots as functions of $x$.

Comment: You have already solved the differential equation. $y$ is not a function of $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, how do I make it a poynomial in x?

Comment: As Stefan said, use $y^2-2y-2\sin x$ and the quadratic formula to isolate an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Quadratic equation will help you get out $y$. Actually the best is to do this:
$y^2-2y+1=2\sin x +c$ (I added $1$ on the left, and constant + 1 is still a constant). This way the quadratic formula is not needed, as you can simply take the square root: $y=1+\sqrt{2\sin x + c}$.

Comment: You won't make it a polynomial, but you can express $y$ as a function of $x$

Comment: Stefan's comment has a typo; it should say "polynomial of degree 2 in $y$" (not "in $x$").

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  y^2-2y &= 2 \sin x + c \\
  y^2-2y + 1 &= 2 \sin x + C \\
  (y-1)^2 &= 2 \sin x + C & (C \ge 2)\\ 
  y &= 1 \pm \sqrt{2 \sin x + C}
\end{align}